# Date-derived field not updating with core data change

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, delegates, uitextfield

I have a view controller that implements `UITextViewDelegate`, `UITextFieldDelegate`, and `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`. It is a `UIViewController`, not a table VC.  Nor is there a table in it.

When I make a change to the Core Data store in another view controller, most text fields and text views in the first VC update  However, I have another text field that shows the date and is derived from `NSDateFormatter, based on a date attribute in Core Data.  It is hidden when nil and when the value is no longer nil, the code to unhide it is not working.

There isn't any code in the VC that says the text views and text fields that DO update specifically are delegates of anything.  They just update naturally.

Perhaps the delegate was set in storyboard, but I don't remember and don't know a way to check what delegates are set in storyboard.

Is there a special date delegate? Or how would I get this text field derived from NSDateFormatter to update?

**EDIT:**

This is where the date is displayed in a method called updateInterface called within `viewWillAppear`

```
//Here is an example of a label that does update when data changes.
self.nameLabel.text = self.item.name; //this sets name...It updates when name is changed.

//Here is the data label that is not changing from hidden to not hidden.
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY 'at' h:mma"];
    NSString *date = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.item.date];

 if (self.item.date!=nil) {
        self.dateLabel.text =date;
  else {
        self.dateLabel.hidden = YES;
    }
```

Comment: Show some code... there are several places where those text views and text fields might be updated.

Comment: @pbasdf see code added above.  Key issue is that it remains hidden.

Comment: Try `self.dateLabel.hidden = NO;` after `self.dateLabel.text = date`.  It doesn't get "unhidden" just because you set a value.

Comment: That did the trick!  Many thanks.